# The app doesn't receive SkuDetailsList (empty list) for "1 year, prepaid" type of subscription but it works fine for "Yearly, auto-renewing" type

Tags: android, android-inapp-purchase

I have created two subscriptions at Google Play Console for my app

[image]

One is "1 year, prepaid" type of subscription and another one is "Yearly, auto-renewing" type of subscription.

Only the "Yearly, auto-renewing" subscription works fine for the app and I can get `SkuDetails` using In App Purchase API:

[image]

For the **prepaid** one I receive empty sku details list:

[image]

What can be the problem? Why does only auto renews subscriptions work but prepaid ones don't?

[image]

[image]